Mounting a SHR RAID without data loss
Someone deleted a storage group on my Synology... It's highly critical for my business to run.
When digging deeper, I found that LVM's VG was removed, and I got PV UUID associated to it.
On the other hand, I have got 4 disks with 3 partitions each. all the /dev/sd*1 are bound in RAID 1 under /dev/md0 and /dev/sd*2 under /dev/md1. It remains all the big device blocks /dev/sd*5.
Problem : fdisk -l states that these partitions are Linux RAID but I have though:
# mdadm --examine /dev/sda5
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda5.

Same for the other ones. Of course:
# mdadm --assemble /dev/md2 /dev/sd{a,b,c,d}5
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda5
mdadm: /dev/sda5 has no superblock - assembly aborted

Question : how to reconstruct SHR array properly to get back my PV with good UUID to reconstruct my data?
Many, many thanks
